# JsonFormat$Value.hasLenient() Error on Rest Call

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, spring-resttemplate

I'm building a set of microservices in Spring Boot. I've got one service which interfaces with the database and has a series of RESTful endpoints which other apps can hit. Many of these table entities are complex objects and are served up as a JSON object but some are simple parameters and so are served as strings. When I hit the main DB service endpoints, all data is returned fine without issue.

I have a series of other applications which consume this data in various ways. Because many objects are reused across applications (the DB service response shape, the person entity POJO, etc), I've got a package made with some common classes. Each app imports these common classes and then makes calls to the main DB service via `RestTemplate`. Because the response is always wrapped in a standard way, I am getting the values by performing an exchange which expects a `ParameterizedTypeReference` of the response wrapper with the appropriate POJO or Java variable (String, int, etc).

As of 5 months ago, all was good. The app was deployed to a server and is still operating normally. However, I recently went back in to the code in order to make some modifications and now I find that when I run the app locally some of the endpoints fail with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat$Value.hasLenient()Z
```

I thought at first that perhaps the two POMs were out of sync and one was pulling a newer version of Jackson but after hard coding the version in the POM to be 100% certain they were the same (version 2.10.1), it still has the same issue. It should also be noted that the method in the error message appears to have been added in version 2.9 and has not been deprecated as of this moment in time. This error only happens when trying to retrieve data from endpoints returning POJOs and not when the data type is a String. It may also be relevant that the call appears to never actually leave the app before throwing an error as the DB service endpoint never gets hit.

Any ideas why I'm getting this error and how I could resolve it?

Response Object:

```
public class DatabaseServiceResponse<T> {
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private List<T> entities;
    
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    private String error;
    
    [getters and setters ommitted]
}
```

Person Service:

```
public List<Person> getPeople() {
    List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
    HttpHeaders headers = getHeaders();
    HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
    ResponseEntity<DatabaseServiceResponse<Person>> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, new ParamaterizedTypeReference<DatabaseServiceResponse<Person>>() {});  // Fails on this line
    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        people = response.getBody().getEntities();
    } else {
        throw new ServiceException("Error retrieving people");
    }
    return people;
}

public List<String> getPersonTypes() {
    List<String> personTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    HttpHeaders headers = getHeaders();
    HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);
    ResponseEntity<DatabaseServiceResponse<String>> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, new ParamaterizedTypeReference<DatabaseServiceResponse<String>>() {});  // Works fine here
    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        personTypes = response.getBody().getEntities();
    } else {
        throw new ServiceException("Error retrieving person types");
    }
    return personTypes;
}
```

Person App POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

Common Elements POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE**
I believe the external library and the potentially out-of-sync POM files was a red herring. I have copied all of the relevant classes into the main project to remove the dependency on the external package and I have the same issue. I've also tried completely upgrading all versions to the latest and still no luck. Jackson, for whatever reason, will map JSON to a String or a list of Strings but just will not map my JSON to a POJO.

Comment: have you tried building dependency tree to make sure that there are no transitive dependencies pulled? try using `mvn dependency:tree` and look for all lines with `jackson`.

Comment: When building the dependency tree, all show the same `jackson` version: 2.10.1

Comment: The issue may be related to the `provided` scope that means that such dependency should be [provided by JDK or container](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope), then actual version of the dependency may differ in some environments.  If you use default `compile` scope, this issue should be resolved.

Comment: In addition to Alexs comment - maybe it's worth checking the classpath when running the app, and check if it may contain some unexpected paths.

Comment: Tried changing the scope to compile but no luck - the issue persists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *finally* worked out what was wrong here and it feels so absurd that I don't believe anyone would ever have gotten to the right answer without the code in their hands. It was only by pulling all the code back into one place and then seeking to find another means of mapping the object via Jackson (using an `ObjectMapper` directly as opposed to letting the `RestTemplate` figure that out) that I stumbled upon the true problem.

There is an audit class which is a property on my Person object which contains the normal, basic properties of created by, created date, modified by, modified date. These dates are `LocalDateTime` objects in the standard ISO-8601 format. It turns out that Jackson can no longer process the string straight into the `LocalDateTime` object and needs "help". By adding a setter which takes the date as a string and does a `LocalDateTime.parse(date)` to set the actual property, I'm now able to successfully hit the endpoints at will.

I still have no clue why the exact error above was thrown, but there you have it. By not specifying a way to help translate from a `String` to the `LocalDateTime` object, I received the `JsonFormat$Value.hasLenient()` error from Jackson.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

In my case @Eyowzitgoin's answer helped me figure out my issue. I had a maven dependency conflict on the jackson annotations.

I was trying to run some tests, and all was fine on the command line but intellij had an issue knowing which version to pick. I had `2.10.3` explicitly declared, but `2.8.5` was being picked up through a transitive dependency.

`2.10.3` has a method `JsonFormat$Value.hasLenient`, but `2.8.5` doesn't.

I was using the JsonFormat annotation on a String variable in a pojo, and intellij was expecting to be able to call the method, but was unable to do so.

In my case I didn't resolve the root of the problem because the variable should have been a LocalDate, so I changed the type and removed the annotation and the issue went away.

I would expect that if I'd left the types as they were and the annotation in place, and instead resolved the dependency issue and made sure that only one of the versions was present/declared the issue would also have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**Working on cucumber-report + playwright + java 1.8** 
These dependencies made my day:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).